# При ошибках Memtest86+ значение Err-Bits всегда в одном и том же бите 04000000, но в разных адресах, почему?

Tags: железо, ram

Первый проход проходит успешно, однако со второго и далее начинают появляться ошибки.

Они возникают как бы в случайных местах, но меня волнует, что Err-Bits всегда `04000000`,  а адрес всегда оканчивается на `440` (а стоящая перед этим цифра всегда только `2`, `6`, `a` или `e`).

Как можно объяснить наблюдаемую закономерность? Какое повреждение могло вызвать такой характер ошибок? Надо было чистить окислы или что-то иное?

Проблемная плашка идентифицируется мемтестом как Micron ITC (DDR2 2ГБ), 8 чипов 128X16DDR2 WT с одной стороны, иных опознавательных знаков не обнаружилось.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/326078/how-do-i-interpret-the-statistics-of-a-memtest-run

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я это уже читал, но ответа на свой вопрос там не видел

Comment: Автор предлагает объяснить имеющиеся аномалии в железе читателям, при том что читатели не имеют доступа к железу и никак не могут проверить, в чем же проблема. Это значит что любые ответы по сути будут основаны не на фактах, а на мнениях. Потому этот вопрос следует закрыть.

Comment: @sanmai читатели имеют доступ к железу через мои руки.

Comment: Вы написали ниже что [выкинули проблемную плашку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/994793/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-memtest86/1001964?noredirect=1#comment1696230_1001964). Значит даже у вас самих на руках нет железа с проблемой.

Comment: @sanmai если опустить глаза ещё на несколько десятков пикселей ниже, то можно внезапно заметить комментарий о том, что [у меня железо под рукой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/994793/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-memtest86#comment1696233_1001964).

Comment: Так или иначе это вопрос из серии "у меня тут подземный стук, помогите телепатически найти причину". Кроме того, очень маловероятно что у кого-то ещё когда-либо будет точно такая же проблема, что делает этот вопрос ещё более бесполезным.

Comment: @sanmai очень даже вероятно, что у кого-то где-то ещё когда-либо будет точно такая же проблема, потому что число вариантов поверждения плашки не бесконечное и ничего экзотического с ней не делалось, именно поэтому я и написал этот вопрос сюда.

Comment: [Про устройство памяти и откуда ошибка всегда в одном бите.](https://superuser.com/questions/1289788/why-does-memtest-show-a-bitflip-of-the-same-bit-across-multiple-addresses) Вам надо написать какая у вас память, сколько в ней чипов и так далее, и может быть можно будет сказать что за проблема привела к такому поведению. Если можно.

Comment: Описание теста 10, на котором ошибка: "The bit fade test initializes all of memory with a pattern and then sleeps for a few minutes. Then memory is examined to see if any memory bits have changed. All ones and all zero patterns are used."

Comment: @sanmai дописал в вопрос. Ссылка познавательная, спасибо

Comment: Может быть вы и фото загрузите, чтобы видно было идентификацию на чипах.

Comment: @sanmai а с этим проблематично, они все целиком наклейками обклеены) Сейчас попытаюсь аккуратно отклеить

Comment: Фен вам в помощь.

Comment: @sanmai а вот как раз его под рукой к сожалению нет

Comment: @sanmai аккуратно без фена не очень получилось, но что-то там вроде видно (клик по картинке)

Answer (score 1):

Обычные действия в таких ситуациях:

1. Удаляем плашки памяти по одной, пока ситуация не улучшится. Если ситуация улучшилась, значит плашку памяти в утиль.
2. Все плашки поменяли, но проблема остается. Значит проблема на уровень выше - где-то в районе чипсета или в части процессора.
3. Можно попробовать заменить процессор. Если это поможет, значит вы нашли виновника.
4. Если замена и переставление всего что есть не помогает, то значит остается последний виновник - материнская плата.
5. Если на плате есть явные дефекты, например - пришедшие в негодность конденсаторы, можно попробовать их поменять. Если нет очевидных дефектов, и нет возможности как-то их найти, значит только и остается что снять исправные компоненты и отправить неисправные в утиль.

Comment: Я спрашивал не что делать, а почему результат такой. Проблемную плашку я выкинул ещё до того, как написал сюда вопрос.

Comment: В таком случае это вопрос под закрытие. Удаленно, не имея железа под рукой, на него невозможно дать объективный ответ.

Comment: У меня железо под рукой (я выкинул его не настолько далеко), и я могу сделать любые действия, необходимые для уточнения вопроса.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96079/discussion-on-answer-by-sanmai---memtest86--err-bits--).